# OpenCV 3.0.0 SVM Trained Model Save / Load

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0 and Python 2.7.9 to pull images of detected objects out of a live video stream and to categorize them as either being in a class of specific objects or not using the OpenCV Machine Learning (cv2.ml) Support Vector Machine (SVM).

The code that I use to train the SVM generates SIFT keypoints in the images, uses KMEANS clustering, and then feeds into the SVM training algorithm. All of that works fine, but because it isn't necessarily a part of the required operational code, I did it separately and save the SVM model to a .dat file using:

svm was created with cv2.ml.SVM_create()

svm.save('datafile.dat')

The problem is that the svm.load() function is not implemented at all in OpenCV 3.0.0.

I've tried to use the StatModel(model) to load as well and that didn't work either.

I'm pretty invested in the python portion of this project so far and would rather not re-program it as C++ and now that I have the SVM working on the training side, would prefer not to use something in SciPy.

I'm hoping that the load feature is somehow renamed and just not well documented. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is a [bug](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4969). See also this [question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/69027/svmload-module-in-python-opencv3/).

If you check the help for SVM_create() you will see that there is no function like read() or load() but save() (inherited from Algorithm class):

```
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.ml.SVM_create())
```